# How to dynamically assign ID to an li element that is generating dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am generating li element dynamically. but when I am assigning id to this li element as per the below code, I am getting the id value but not the text. What am I doing wrong?

**.js**

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
$.each(months, function (i, v) {
    var li = $('<li id="sp_month_'+ v +'">', { text: v })
    $('#servicePlanMonths').append(li);
});
```

**cshtml**

```
<div class="months-bar">
            <ul id="servicePlanMonths">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes: _“**Important:** If the second argument is passed, the HTML string in the first argument must represent a simple element with no attributes.”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
$.each(months, function (i, v) {
    var li = $('<li id="sp_month_'+ v +'">'+v+'</li>')
    $('#servicePlanMonths').append(li);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oc3cq13x/)

Comment: do you know how can I get li tag left position. I am generating the li dynamically and now I want to find the left most position fo the li tag

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    $.each(months, function (i, v) {
    var li = $('<li>'+v+'</li>');
    var id = "sp_month_"+ v;
    li.attr("id", id);
    $('#servicePlanMonths').append(li);
    });
```

In jQuery you have $(element).attr( "id", "somethig" ); 
Try it [Docs for .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not worked was because you were setting id via concatenation . which prevent appending other properties by using second argument. First argument should be clean object without other properties.

You need to set the id in same way the way you are trying to set text:

```
$.each(months, function (i, v) {
   $('<li />', { id:"sp_month_"+ v,text: v}).appendTo('#servicePlanMonths')
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt58vpw3/)**